# What is the induced representation in this case?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

### Problem

We let $G$ be a finite group and $(e_{g_1}, ..., e_{g_n} )$ be a basis of a complex vector space $V$ indexed by the element in the group $G$. For any $h \in g$ and any vector $x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_g$, we set
$$
h\cdot x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_{hg_i}.
$$
and we use $\chi$ to denote the character of the induced representation. Calculate $\langle \chi, \chi \rangle$

### My thoughts

1. The definition of induced representation, according to Wikipedia, uses a known subgroup. In this case we don't have any known subgroups. So how should I think about the induced representation? I know that if $h$ is the identity element, the trace of the identity representation should be $n$, and if $h$ is not the identity element the trace  should be $0$. But I am not sure how I would represent it with the correct notation.
2. We know that $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \overline{\chi(g)}\chi(g)$. How do I incorporate $h$ to $\chi$.

Comment: The identity element maps to the identity matrix, so it's trace is $n$, not $n^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yeah, that is true. I was thinking about the multiplication in the hermitian inner product. Will correct it.

Comment: Without referencing a subgroup, the question doesn't make sense. Where is this problem from?

Comment: But $\chi(g)$ is the trace of $g$, and you know what $\chi(g)$ is for all $g \in G$, so you can calculate $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle$.

Comment: "induced" here just seems like the wrong word; I think the intended meaning is "the representation on $V$ defined by that formula"